# Spring Boot unable to find the images in /resources/static/images folder

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to load image in html like this

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-4"><img class="img-fluid" src="../static/images/zep.png" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h1>Coming Soon.</h1></div>
            <!-- <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><p>Subscribe to our newsletter and stay tuned</p></div> -->
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><button class="btn btn-custom">Subscribe</button></div> -->
    </div>
</body>
```

And this is my folder structure 
[image]

So when I run it, I get

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of zep.png:1 404 ()
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Still not loading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not include `static` in the `img` tag's `src`. Resources placed in `src/main/resources/static` will be served from the root of your application. This means that `src/main/resources/static/images/zep.png` will be served from `/images/zep.png`.