# 404 for static image at spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

In the `html` file, there is an image:

```
        <div class="login-branding">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="../static/images/logo.png" alt="Clevex" title="Clevex"></a>
    </div>
```

At the address of http://localhost:8090/login, I look at console and see:

> GET http://localhost:8090/static/images/logo.png 404

But while application is up, if I go to

http://localhost:8090/images/logo.png

this url, I can see the image without any error or warning at the console of `chrome` browser.

This is my security config:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

 http.cors().and().csrf().disable();

        String[] resources = new String[]{
                "/",
                "/home",
                "/pictureCheckCode",
                "/include/**",
                "/css/**",
                "/icons/**",
                "/images/**",
                "/js/**",
                "/resources/**",
                "/layer/**",
                "/static/**",
                "/js/**",
                "/img/**",
                "/webjars/**"
        };

   http
                .authorizeRequests()

                .antMatchers(resources).permitAll()
```

I also added `@EnableAutoConfiguration` but it did not do anything. And gave error also.

I do not want to use `addResourceHandlers` becvause it is spring boot and it should do autoconfiguration.

The directories are like this:

```
src
-main
-resources
--static
---images
----logo.png
```

This is how application starts:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class InternalApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InternalApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Everything inside the `static` directory is served at the root of your web application. So `/static/images/logo.png` is served by Spring Boot at `/images/logo.png`.

So replace:

```
src="../static/images/logo.png"
```

with:

```
src="/images/logo.png"
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56196207/11369236

I changed

```
<a href="index.html"><img src="../static/images/logo.png" alt="Clevex" title="Clevex"></a>
```

to

```
            <a href="index.html"><img src="/images/logo.png" alt="Clevex" title="Clevex"></a>
```

I was confused because of `Intellij Idea`.

In the `HTML` code, if I click `../static/images/logo.png`, it can go to image.

But when I click `/images/logo.png` in the HTML code, it does not go , also `sonar` gives warning for it.